# Getting the records on right table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am facing some tables join issue in MySQL. Can anyone help me. I have two tables in mysql database. I want to join both tables and get the records. Here is the structure of the both table.

```
exam_attend
===========
id
student_id

Answer
======
id
student_id



exam_attend
===========
id  student_id
--  ----------
1   10
2   11
3   12

Answer
======
id  student_id
--  ----------
1   10
2   10
3   13
4   12
5   14
```

I want list of the user who giving the answer without attending exam. Please help me.

## Desired result

```
id  student_id
--  ----------
3   13
5   14
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT A.id, A.student_id FROM Answer A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN exam_attend E ON E.student_id=A.student_id  
WHERE E.student_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Below SQL useful to you.

```
select id,  student_id from  Answer
    where student_id  not in (select distinct student_id from  exam_attend)
```

Comment: What happens if the sub-query returns a NULL value? Why SELECT DISTINCT in the sub-query?

Comment: @jarlh The distinct is unnecessary but what if the sub query returns null? it will still work.

Comment: @sagi, have you tried a NOT IN when the sub-query returns null? Do you think that's what OP is expecting?

Comment: @jarlh Yes actually I did, and yes thats what the OP wants.. Unless I'm missing something here. It will select * from answer for all the students id that doesn't appear in exam table..

Comment: @sagi, if the sub-query returns a NULL, no rows at all will be returned.

Comment: @jarlh Well, I was testing it on oracle but assumed that it would work on other dbms too.. on mysql if the subquery returns null it won't work? really?

Comment: @jarlh Good to know:)